# Create custom type from object by extracting types of object's values

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a type from this object:

```
export const AppStore = {
    LoggedInUserState: {
        stateName: "LoggedInUserState",
        stateModel: LoggedInUserStateModel,
    },
    JwtDecodedUserState: {
        stateName: "JwtDecodedUserState",
        stateModel: JwtDecodedUserStateModel,
    },
    LoaderState: {
        stateName: "LoaderState",
        stateModel: LoaderStateModel,
    },
} as const;
```

I want the type to be an object whose keys are exactly `stateName` and values will be exactly `stateModel`

The resulted type I want:

```
{
    "LoggedInUserState": LoggedInUserStateModel,
    "JwtDecodedUserState": JwtDecodedUserStateModel,
    "LoaderState": LoaderStateModel,
}
```

Solution I've tried:

```
export type TAppStore = typeof AppStore;
export type StateKeys = keyof TAppStore;

export type AppState = {
    [stateKey: TAppStore[StateKeys]["stateName"]]: TAppStore[StateKeys]["stateModel"];
};
```

But I'm getting error: `TS1337: An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.`

The error underlines the `stateKey` in my solution as incorrect.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try it like this:

```js
export type TAppStore = typeof AppStore;

export type AppState = {
    -readonly [
      K in keyof TAppStore as TAppStore[K]["stateName"]
    ]: TAppStore[K]["stateModel"]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=18&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wIJjAZRtYOAXjgG8BYAKDhrgBkIBzR4AEwElkBVVYKPAIYxgALjJVakuOiHAAcgIC2ouACIGzNpx59Bw1QBoJUmjOEBZCK2AAbMasPGaAXyPVaAKQDuMACLAka1YdfhhZMQp3EzN5JRVVbz8AqzYQvWBHKKkYy2s7OAAGN0lXJ3oIAWtQ8PEsyRiFZXsGSt0w-WKTaXbgXNsxGCgAV2BOlzdnOAFURBR0AG4qKlBIWDgYAE8wQgAVLFx8KEISTe2IADM4fbwCRcpl8Gh4U8JrnuJayQBaI8qUGw2cAA2gBpOAAS2QcAA1sANhc4HtsDcjlMZkiDgRQQBdIGqBpxVTY7FiDEo4A4vE5FI2IlUZxAA)

Comment: Thankyou, your solution worked. I have never used the `-` symbol that you have used before `readonly` keyword. Can you explain or guide me to some sources that explain this?
Thankyou

Comment: You declared the object with `as const` which results in lots of `readonly` modifiers in the type definition. When using mapped types, the `readonly` modifier stays for each property. When you want to remove `readonly` you can put `- readonly` in front of the index signature of the mapped type. and voila: the `readonly` is gone

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21919